# Trying to make a learning to multiply

Tags: javascript

The problem is that when I put in the correct answer the text does not change to green and when it is incorrect it does not change to red. I think there is a problem that I don't get the input value but can find the fix for it.

```js
var firstArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var secondArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

var first = firstArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * firstArray.length)];
var second = secondArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * secondArray.length)];

var sum = firstArray[first - 1] * secondArray[second - 1];

function fn1(sum, n1) {

  var n1 = document.getElementById("n1").value;
  if (sum < n1) {
    document.getElementById("pp").style.background = "green";
  } else if (sum > n1) {
    document.getElementById("p").style.background = "red";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("p").style.background = "blue";
    document.getElementById("pp").style.background = "blue";
  }
};

document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = first;
document.getElementById("pp").innerHTML = second;

document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = first;
document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = second;
document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = sum;
```

```html
<h1>
  <a id="a"></a> *
  <a id="b"></a> = <input type="text" id="n1" name="txt"></h1>

<button onclick="fn1()" id="btn1">Clcik me</button>

<p id="p"></p>
<p id="pp"></p>
<p id="sum"></p>
<p id="test"></p>
```

Comment: n1 is both a parameter and a declared variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to the function does not pass any arguments

Answer (score 0):

your function fn1() takes no arguements

```js
    var firstArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    var secondArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

    var first= firstArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * firstArray.length)];
    var second= secondArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * secondArray.length)];

    var sum = firstArray[first- 1] * secondArray[second - 1];

    function fn1() {

        var n1 = document.getElementById("n1").value;
        if (sum < n1) {
            document.getElementById("pp").style.background = "green";
        } else if (sum > n1) {
            document.getElementById("p").style.background = "red";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("p").style.background = "blue";
            document.getElementById("pp").style.background = "blue";
        }
    };

    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = first;
    document.getElementById("pp").innerHTML = second;

    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = first;
    document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = second;
    document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = sum;
```

```html
<h1>Learn to Multiply</h1>

<h1> <a id="a"></a> * <a id="b"></a> = <input type="text" id="n1" name="txt"></h1>

<button onclick="fn1()" id="btn1">Clcik me</button>

<p id="p"></p>
<p id="pp"></p>
<p id="sum"></p>
<p id="test"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
// first remove the parameters
function fn1() { 
  var n1 = document.getElementById("n1").value;
  // I think you want green when is equal
  if (sum == n1) {
    document.getElementById("pp").style.background = "green";
  } else if (sum > n1) {
    document.getElementById("p").style.background = "red";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("p").style.background = "blue";
    document.getElementById("pp").style.background = "blue";
  }
};
```